# C file solves the task, then prints out random characters in the command and crashes itself

Tags: c, pointers, crash, sentence

So my task is to take a sentence and print out the first one in alphabetical order. 
For example `ball car tshirt` should print `ball` which I managed to do. The tricky bit is when two words have the same first letter then it should do more comparison. I did this messy algorithm which works but prints out random characters and crashes the program (Screenshot below).
The code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char str[100];
    char *p, *pz , *p1, *p2;

    printf("\nEnter sentence: ");
    fgets(str, 60, stdin);

    p=str;
    pz=p;

    while(*p!='\0'){
        if(*p == ' '){
            p++;
            if(*p<*pz){
                pz=p;
            }else if(*pz == *p){
                p1=p;   //temp
                p2=pz;  //temp
                p1++;
                p2++;
                while(*p2 != '\0' && *p1 != '\0'){

                    if (*p1 != '\0'){
                        pz=p;
                        break;
                    }else if(*p2 != '\0'){
                        break;
                    }else {
                        if(*p1 < *p2){
                            pz=p;
                            break;
                        }else{
                            p1++;
                            p2++;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        p++;
    }



    while(*pz != ' '){
        printf("%c", *pz);
        pz++;
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

pointer pz is supposed to be the one that will be printed out, pointer p is the one doing all the work and pointers p1 and p2 are temporary.

[image: The problem[1]]

Comment: I'm afraid that code is practically incomprehensible and arguably needs a full re-write. Suggest applying best practices: designing the algorithm before coding, breaking up the implementation into functions, using meaningful variable names (difficult to follow `p` vs `p1` vs `p2` vs `pz`), testing smaller parts of the code as you go.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you should use `std::string` for the text and `std::vector` to contain the text lines.  You can use `std::istringstream` with the first string to extract the words.

Comment: Can you paste the text of your output?  The image is difficult to read.

Comment: You'll need to step through with a debugger.   Look carefully at what character `p` points at - it needs to point both at an element of `str` and not past the end of the data read using `fgets()`, but neither condition is being checked or enforced.    Other pointers `pz`, `p1`, etc are also being assigned values (or incremented) based on `p` , again without checking they are valid.

Comment: I am completely aware that the code is incomprehensible I am just looking for some simple answers and will rethink it tomorrow after some sleep.

Comment: You should pick a *single* language, as the answers may be different depending on the language choice.  The C and C++ languages are distinct.  The C++ language has algorithms, iterators and containers; the C language doesn't.

Comment: The output is 
Enter sentence: marinko mari marin
marin
vVv ░< Ç a σ@                            Yc;w ░< @c;w▄ a |pw ░< Pæ ╦@ ╡■a ║■a  a ┐■a  a  ░< P a 6@    Ç
         ░<                                         î a     Σ a @áqw$ôè}    ∞ a Σ{pw    ▄Årw        ╨@  ░<